# win service or scheduled task to Periodically Call a Web Service?

Tags: web-services, windows-services, scheduled-tasks

I have a web service which I would like to call on a scheduled basis.  Currently, I have a scheduled task setup to execute the call. Here's a [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2005/10/24/428303.aspx) [Jon Galloway's](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway) post on the topic.

I'm planning to switch this out with a Win Service, simply to appease my boss, but I'm wondering what the advantages are (aside from keeping my job ;).

I personally like the script method due to its simplicity, but am curious to know what I'm missing over a Win Service approach..

Answer (score 1):

Reliability is higher with a Windows Service. It can be set to start when the system starts, and to restart automatically if it fails.

Comment: I think I can do all of that with a Scheduled Task.. No?

Comment: No. Automatic restart on failure?

Comment: Also, have you seen how easy it is to write a Windows Service in Visual Studio.NET?

Comment: I've thrown some psuedo try/catch code in my script which logs any failures.  I guess for my purposes, I wouldn't want it to retry until I'd be able to review the issue.  I also think compiling should be left for bigger code/projects.

Comment: So, you haven't seen how easy it is. Besides, code is easier to refactor and reuse than script is. What kind of script? PowerShell, I hope?

Comment: Seriously. Time to write some code. No wonder your boss wants this. He may even want maintainable code, who knows? :-)

Comment: Still haven't given me a good argument to replace my 20 line script with an X amount of lines/compiled Win Service.